# WooCommerce Hides Info from Chrome Download Bar

Tags: woocommerce, header

When a user buys a downloadable product and page redirects to download page, then when users click on link of product to save it, chrome starts to download the link but file size is not known and so progress bar doesnt work.

It frustrates my client.

I've found `function download_headers()` in `class-wc-download-handler.php` and edited it to below code.

because php function `filesize()` doesn't work with non-absolute paths (not with urls, should be `public_html/wordpress/....`  .ex)

Also added `Content-Range` but it still doesn't work.

```
function download_headers( $file_path, $filename ) {
    self::check_server_config();
    self::clean_buffers();
    nocache_headers();

    header( "X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true );
    header( "Content-Type: " . self::get_download_content_type( $file_path )   );
    header( "Content-Description: File Transfer" );
    header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\";" );
    header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );

    $url = $file_path;
    static $regex = '/^Content-Length: *+\K\d++$/im';
    if ( ! $fp = @fopen( $url, 'rb' ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( isset( $http_response_header )
         && preg_match( $regex, implode( "\n", $http_response_header ), $matches ) ) {
        return (int)$matches[0];
    }
    $size = strlen( stream_get_contents( $fp ) );

    header( "Content-Range: 0-" . ($size-1) . "/" . $size );

    header( "Content-Length: " . $size );
}
```

Comment: Please write your question with proper edits (punctuation, capitalisation, grammar, white space between words ....etc.)